# Why does my JavaScript Audio Autoplay not work?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

When a user visits my website music should start playing automatically. The user does not need to click on a button. Users just visit my site, the page will be loaded, and the audio will start automatically.

I was trying using below code, but it is not working.

[W3 Schools audio auto play](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_autoplay.asp)

Please help me to understand why this doesn't work?

When the user visits my site the music should be automatically started. They shouldn't be able to stop the music. After playing the full track it should not repeat.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_autoplay it

Comment: "Please give me full solution.". This is not what Stackoverflow is about. Try your best and come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: fixed all the grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some devices like smart phones, videos and audios only will play by user generated events like click and ...

If you play audio on page loading event it does not work in some device.
But playing audio on page loading will works properly in PCes browsers.